# Cannot start web WhatsApp after last update on 2nd April 2018

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, web, whatsapp

Whatsapp Web is not not loading on chrome/firefox since April 2, 2018.

**Error Snippet**

```
/app.f7c554586d665fe6fd2e.js:33 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier progress.54976898720da809471639fb0b654280.js:2 
Uncaught TypeError: window.Exe is not a function
    at i (progress.54976898720da809471639fb0b654280.js:2)
    at HTMLScriptElement.u.onload (progress.54976898720da809471639fb0b654280.js:2)
```

**Error Screenshot**

[image]

The issue appears on incognito/private mode as well.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Tried updating and resetting chrome, but nothing has worked out for me. Have raised a ticket with Whatsapp Web at **`webclient_web@support.whatsapp.com`**. Let's hope it gets resolved soon.

Comment: Were you using selenium or any other automation? Whatsapp Web is working on other devices, maybe our devices are blocked.

Comment: @Nik on which device you checked?I tried on multiple systems but it doesn't seem working without any automation.

Comment: I tried using whatsapp web on chrome mobile. It is also getting stuck.  My roommate is able to run whatsapp web in a jiffy, probably because he is using a vpn.

Comment: Wierdly, working fine on Opera. But not on Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: I am not sure but it looks like when app.f7c554586d665fe6fd2e.js file is loaded from 169.44.36.76 server then whatsapp does not work.
@Nik: Can you please check yours? To check, select this file in network tab of developer tool of chrome and check Xconnected-to response header.

Comment: WhatsApp team accepted this to be an issue and are working to fix it. But not committed anything on date and time to fix it.

Comment: @raja That's right via: HTTP/1.1 169.44.36.76:443. I just wish it's fixed ASAP.

Comment: according to this link https://www.quora.com/My-WhatsApp-web-is-not-working-Im-using-the-Chrome-browser-on-my-Windows-8-1-laptop-and-the-internet-speed-is-good-I-opened-web-whatsapp-com-and-the-QR-code-doesnt-load-up-How-can-I-fix-this just clear cookies and restart chrome, for me clear cookies from settings better

Comment: I'm in the same case; it works on my laptop but not on this machine (neither chrome nor firefox). I cleared the cache, deleted the cookies and even performed a file comparison (with the working version) but they are identical. I really have no idea whatsappening.

Answer (score -1):

I am also facing the same issue. To get things working, I downloaded the native application for my OS from

https://www.whatsapp.com/download/

This is working well.

Comment: Question is about web.whatsapp.com and the problem disappeared yesterday, thanks to all who raised tickets. Also, the native application is anyway needed even for web.whatsapp.com to work.

Comment: I don't think so that the issue is completely resolved.It's now a random issue, sometimes it loads and sometimes not.

Comment: It's been working ever since for me. Do you still face issues?